# conffiles syntax

Tags: debian, packaging

I'm trying to find what is the syntax of conffiles.

I'm creating several packages using a single rules file and if I put the configuration files into conffiles I get an error when building the packages (since the files are only present in two of the 9 packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using debhelper, you can name the conffile file after the package name, just like with the install files. An example file name would be `"mypackage.conffiles"`. With debhelper, any file that does not follow the `"maypackage.myfile"` format applies to all binary packages from the source.

The conffiles file is described in the [dh_installdeb manpage](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=1&query=dh_installdeb&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en).

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the downvote, @jordanm, but your answer doesn't address what the OP actually asked (which was frustrating when coming here from google). The syntax of the `conffiles` file is defined in the [deb-conffiles](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/deb-conffiles.5.html) manpage, excerpted here:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>   A package declares its list of conffiles by including a conffiles
>   file in its control archive (i.e. DEBIAN/conffiles during package
>   creation).
>
>   This file contains a list of files, one per line.  Trailing
>   whitespace will be trimmed, and empty lines will be ignored.
> ```
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> ```
>   /usr/local/etc/alternatives/README
>   /usr/local/etc/cron.daily/dpkg
>   /usr/local/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg
>   /usr/local/etc/logrotate.d/dpkg
> ```

Comment: Actually, the problem is that the question's title and first sentence didn't really summarize the question; Jordan correctly answered the body of the question.  Have an upvote anyway; it's a useful answer.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Sorry @jordanm, and thanks Toby Speight for the clarification. I don't use debhelper, so I didn't realize that was an implicit part of the OP.